# Replace values between dataframes with different sizes and multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have 2 dataframes, from different sizes, `df1 = (578, 81)` and `df2 = (1500, 59)`, all lines on `df1 exists in df2`, and all columns in `df2 exists in df1`, my problem is, I have a value that i want to update in df1 based on `6 conditions`, so to update the `column X`, the values at columns `X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Z1 and Z2` must be equal on both DataFrames.

On java I would do somenthing like:

```
for(i=0;i<df1.length;i++){
    for(k=0;k<df2.length;k++){
        if(df1[i][1]==df2[k][1] && df1[i][2]==df2[k][2] ...){
            df1[i][0] = df2[k][0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see [How to create good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and provide a [mcve] for your issue with sample input and output data, so that we can give more specific help

Comment: I have no idea how to do that, so i can't provide a reproducible example, i will just load the dataframes from a csv file, that is as far as i got.

Comment: Hi Pablo, you could just copy some of the lines out of your csv.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily use `numpy.where`. And i think it should work best in this case too.

Let's say you have the following DataFrames

```
import pandas as pd

df1=pd.DataFrame({'X':[1,3,4,6,5],
                  'X1':[2,3,4,6,3],
                  'Y1':[4,2,1,51,3],
                  'Z1':[2,3,4,1,5]})

df2=pd.DataFrame({'L':[2,3,4,1,4],
                  'X2':[2,3,4,6,5],
                  'Y2':[4,3,4,6,3],
                  'Z2':[2,2,1,51,3]})
```

And you want to change the value of X based on the conditions if `X1==X2 & Y1==Y2 & Z1==Z2` . Also lets say the value you want to update is from column L in this case.

You can use `numpy.where` like this

```
df1['X']=np.where((df1['X1']==df2['X2'])&(df1['Y1']==df2['Y2'])&(df1['Z1']==df2['Z2']),df2['L'],,df1['X'])
```

It would only change the first row as the conditions only gets satisfied there. This function is changing the values to `df2['L']` if it meets the condition and keeping the original values if the conditions are not met.

Read more about [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

**Update: The dataframes in the question are not equal. It doesn't matter if they don't have equal columns but the rows should be equal for the sake of comparison. Below is the example in which the two data frames are not equal and how `numpy.where` is performed in that case.**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1=pd.DataFrame({'X':[1,3,4,6,5],
                  'X1':[2,3,4,6,3],
                  'Y1':[4,3,1,51,3],
                  'Z1':[2,3,4,1,5]})

df2=pd.DataFrame({'L':[2,3,4,1,4,5,1],
                  'X2':[2,3,4,6,5,2,3],
                  'Y2':[4,3,4,6,3,8,7],
                  'Z2':[2,3,1,51,3,9,9],
                  'R2':[2,5,1,2,7,3,9]})

#make both the dataframes equal

for i in range(len(df2)-len(df1)):
    df1=df1.append(pd.Series(),ignore_index=True)

df1['X']=np.where((df1['X1']==df2['X2'])&(df1['Y1']==df2['Y2'])&(df1['Z1']==df2['Z2']),df2['L'],df1['X'])

#drop those null values which have been appended above to get back to original
df1=df1.dropna(how='all')
```

Comment: I get an error: ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects, i got the same error whe i tried using a mask,.

Comment: Check the updated answer! The error happened because of unequal rows in the two dataframes. Proposed solution is adding some null values to the dataframe to make it equal and then removing those values. Also you should copy and paste some lines from your excel files if they are not confidential to give us a better idea about what you are looking to achieve. You can also change the values if the data is confidential.

Comment: I believe yout answer is comparing row by row, and it's not working, i have to search df2 for a match, and update X for the match, for exaomple, the row 1 of df1 is a match with row 3 of df2, df1 is a filtered df2, with bad rows deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Do the 6 columns make a row unique? 
If so, I would use merge:

```
columns_join= ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6']
columns_update= ['upd1', 'upd2', 'upd3']

df_merged= df_to_update[columns_join].merge(df_source[columns_join + columns_update], on=columns_join, how='left', suffixes=['', '_src'], indicator='_join_ind')

for col in columns_update:
    df_to_update.loc[df_merged['_join_ind']=='both', col]= df_merged[col + '_src']

# now df_to_update contains the result
```

If the 6 fields do not identify a row (could result in more rows), you would need to make the merged result unique afterwards, but in that case, your Java version would also just always result in the values of the last row.
In that case you can use `DataFrame.grouby` and e.g. `last` as the aggregation function.

EDIT: in case you need to apply an aggregation, it's probably best to apply the aggregation to the dataframe you take the values. To aggregate it accordingly using the last value of each group and merge it afterwards, just replace the line with the `.merge` above by:

```
df_agg= df_source.groupby(columns_join)[columns_update].aggregate('last')
df_merged= df_to_update[columns_join].merge(df_source[columns_join + columns_update], left_on=columns_join, right_index=True, how='left', suffixes=['', '_src'], indicator='_join_ind')
```

Comment: For future use, I think it is missing columns_update on on=, i think it is the solution for my case, but i'm getting a key error, missing 2 indexes, the firsts 10 rows the values are equals, this can be for a few rows that doesn't have a match? but there should be a match for every single row

Comment: Thank you. Your right, at first I used the list in that place instead of the variable.

Comment: So i found the error, the column name had 2 spaces more in one of the dataframes, but i still get an error of key missing on the de column that i want to update, and i checked, they are correct

Comment: I'm lost. What did you try and what error do you get? Did you additionally apply the aggregation I proposed above?